# Excel VBA ProperCase function

Tags: excel, text, case

I use the following code to put several cells into Proper case and it works just fine. But is there any way to modify this so that it doesn't change the case of letters already present? An example would be leaving "McDonald" or "MacDonald" alone? I can't figure out how to "adjust" only the first letter of each of two names the cells.

```
Range("A6") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A6"))
Range("A8") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A8"))
Range("A10") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A10"))
Range("A11") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A11"))
Range("A12") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A12"))
Range("A13") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A13"))
Range("A14") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A14"))
Range("A15") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A15"))
Range("A16") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A16"))
Range("A17") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A17"))
Range("A18") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A18"))
Range("A20") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A20"))
Range("A21") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A21"))
Range("A22") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Range("A22"))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for sanity sakes, if you go with `WorksheetFunction.Proper`, or iterate over any `Range` for that matter, then first initialize it and iterate over it, like:

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("A6,A8,A10:A18,A20:A22")
For Each cl In rng
    cl.Value = Application.Proper(cl.Value)
Next
```

However, `VBA` got it's own variant called `StrConv`.

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("A6,A8,A10:A18,A20:A22")
For Each cl In rng
    cl.Value = StrConv(cl.Value, vbProperCase)
Next
```

---

Now, to answer your question, both options will **not** leave alone what's there allready. In that case, throw together some `Left`, `UCase` and `Mid` and you are ready to go:

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("A6,A8,A10:A18,A20:A22")
For Each cl In rng
    cl.value = UCase(Left(cl.value, 1)) & Mid(cl.value, 2)
Next
```

---

**Tip:** Make sure to use *Explicit* sheet references as `rng` now refers to the *Implicit* `ActiveSheet`

Would you have multiple words within a string you might want to split the string, iterate over each word in an array and join them back together. For example:

```
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("A6,A8,A10:A18,A20:A22")
For Each cl In rng
    tmp = Split(cl.Value, " ")
    For x = LBound(tmp) To UBound(tmp)
        tmp(x) = UCase(Left(tmp(x), 1)) & Mid(tmp(x), 2)
    Next x
    cl.Value = Join(tmp, " ")
Next
```

Comment: Ok, wow! You answered not just the question I asked, but one that I didn't know how to ask. Both of these will make my project go MUCH smoother! Thank you so much! (I upvoted and checked that you answered it.)

Comment: This is a pale imitation of what Proper does.

Comment: @JvdV `PROPER` capitalises _all_ words in a string (and lower cases subsequent letters, which is the OPs problem),  and identifies words as seperated by non-alpha characters.  You answer only examines the first character of a string - a _very_ different algorithm.  If that's what the OP wants, then fine, but to pass it off as a variant of `PROPER` is at best disingenuous.